# Parameters.Add() is not working in case of queries involving "if exists" statement in c#

Tags: c#, sap-ase

Please have a look at the following code

```
string SearchQuery = @"if exists (select * from table where colName = @colNameVal) select 1 else select 0";
AseConnection connection = new AseConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
connection.Open();
try
{
    AseCommand selectCommand = new AseCommand(SearchQuery, connection);
    selectCommand.Parameters.Add(new AseParameter("@colNameVal", AseDbType.NVarChar, 13)).Value = "123";
    int doesValExist = (int)selectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{

}
```

I am using Sybase.AdoNet4.AseClient. The above code is throwing AseException with the following message

> " Must declare variable '@colNameVal' ".

But the following query is working `select * from table where colName = @colNameVal`.

So I am assuming that there is some issue with adding parameters in case of if exists statement. Is there any work around to pass parameters ?

Comment: Try setting: selectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text

Comment: Have you  tried `Parameters.AddWithValue`

Comment: tried both your suggestions, not working. Getting the same error.

Comment: He there. Refer to this (http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc20066.1570/html/adonet/Inserting_data_command.htm) link for using parameters with Sybase in .net

Comment: If exists() is not mentioned in the link.

Comment: What does your connection string look like?

Comment: I am using ldap and other queries involving parameters are working. Only issue is with if exists().

Answer (score 0):

```
string SearchQuery = @"select count(*) from table where colName = @colNameVal";
AseConnection connection = new AseConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
connection.Open();
try
{
    AseCommand selectCommand = new AseCommand(SearchQuery, connection);
    selectCommand.Parameters.Add(new AseParameter("@colNameVal", AseDbType.NVarChar, 13)).Value = "123";
    int doesValExist = (int)selectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{

}
```

Comment: You could just use literal formatting, perhaps this might work. I haven't work with Sybase in years, the previous code I had up worked in SQL Server.

Comment: This would work but there is a possibility of sql injection that is why I want to avoid this.

Comment: Made a slight change to code above. Perhaps go with that method. There must be some unusual behaviour with IF EXITS in Sybase. The other alternative, which I'm sure you've considered, is to use a stored proc.